# Sending data from android studio app to server

Tags: android-studio

I am trying to send data from my android studio app to mysql php server and here is my code, the program can run but my server cannot receive data from my app. Did I make a mistake somewhere in my coding?

My android studio app coding

```
package com.sp.toilert;

import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.nfc.NdefMessage;
import android.nfc.NdefRecord;
import android.nfc.NfcAdapter;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.List;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

NfcAdapter nfcAdapter;
TextView txtTagContent;
private BluetoothAdapter myBluetooth = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(com.sp.toilert.R.layout.activity_main);

    checkBTState();
    nfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
    txtTagContent = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtTagContent);

}

public void buttonOnClick(View v) {

new SubmitData().execute();  //do something when button clicked  

}

public class SubmitData extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {

        try {

            postData();

        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    //this function is the main thing that will upload the data to the server
    public void postData() {
        // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://172.22.47.245/notthatdirty.php");

        try {
            // these are all the fields that will be submitted
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
            //nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("MyName","MyValue"));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("cubicle_ID", "100003")); //send data to server
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("issue", "dirty")); //send data to server
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            // Execute HTTP Post Request
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        }
    }
}
```

My server coding

```
<h1>WELCOME TO TOILERT</h1></P>

<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "toilert";
$password = "toilert";
$dbname = "cleaning_db";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
echo "Connected successfully";

//http://localhost/toilet-backend/backend.php?dirty=1&cubicleID=10003
//GET the data from android
/*
$dirty = $_GET["dirty"]; //1 for true . 0 for false
$emergency = $_GET["emergency"]; //1 for true . 0 for false
$faulty = $_GET["faulty"]; //1 for true . 0 for false
*/

$issue = htmlspecialchars($_GET["issue"]); // Sanitize input with         htmlspecialchars
$cubicleID = $_GET['cubicleID'];

//Check if the request has been sent before
//ensure no duplicate toilet data
$query = "SELECT * FROM cleaner_request WHERE cubicle_id = $cubicleID";
$result = $conn->query($query);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
$json = array("status" => 200, "msg" => "Complaint has already been         created");
echo json_encode($json);
} else {
switch ($issue) {
    case "dirty":
    case "emergency":
    case "faulty":
        $query = "INSERT INTO cleaner_request (cubicle_id, $issue) VALUES     ('$cubicleID', '1')";
        break;
    default:
        $error = "Invalid status";
}
if (empty($error)) {
    $result = $conn->query($query);
    echo "Data written to Database";
    $json = array("status" => 200, "msg" => "Complaint has been successfully  created");
    } else {
    echo "error" ;
    //$json = array("status" => 418, "msg" => $error);

}
echo json_encode($json);
/* Ben commented this out. Because code
if ($dirty == 1) {  //dirty
    $query = "INSERT INTO cleaner_request (cubicle_id,dirty) VALUES    ('$cubicleID','$dirty')";
    $result = $conn->query($query);
    $json = array("status" => 200, "msg" => "Complaint has been successfully  created");
    echo json_encode($json);
    } else if ($dirty == 0) { //clean

    }
   */
    //check require location
    require 'C:/xampp/htdocs/toilet-backend/twilio-php-master/Services/Twilio.php';
 $AccountSid = "AC52a80f076cca00c9547fdfd17bf4fbbb";
 $AuthToken = "b145c2d4f7b722fe79cbe38f3009afcc";

 // Step 3: instantiate a new Twilio Rest Client
$client = new Services_Twilio($AccountSid, $AuthToken);
$client->account->messages->create(array(
    'To' => "+65 9067 9919",
    'From' => "+15672420325",
    'Body' => "Greetings, please clean up Cubicle 100 001 and 100 004. Thank you. This service is brought to you by Toilert.",
));
mysqli_close($conn);  //$conn->close();
}
?>
```

[A picture of the server side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uuq9U.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html

Stop stressing and use Volley it worked fine for me.

Volley is an HTTP library that makes networking for Android apps easier and most importantly, faster. Volley is available through the open AOSP repository.

Volley offers the following benefits:

Automatic scheduling of network requests.
Multiple concurrent network connections.
Transparent disk and memory response caching with standard HTTP cache coherence.
Support for request prioritization.
Cancellation request API. You can cancel a single request, or you can set blocks or scopes of requests to cancel.
Ease of customization, for example, for retry and backoff.
Strong ordering that makes it easy to correctly populate your UI with data fetched asynchronously from the network.
Debugging and tracing tools.

Comment: This worked for me. It's easy to use.